# Minimum number of bits required for a range of numbers

Tags: binary, precision, point, floating

Im trying to work out an answer for a question about meassuring pressures.
The meassurments are supposed to be stored in binary floating point format and my task is to determine the minimum number of bits required to do so with some constraints;

Maximum pressure is 1e+07 Pa

Minimum pressure is 10 Pa

Accuracy of meassurments is 0.001 %

So if I understand it correctly, I could happen to measssure

1e+07 + 0.00001 * 1e+07 = 10000100 Pa

and would want to store it precisely. This would mean I would need 24 bits, since

2^23< 10000100 <2^24-1.

Is this including the 1 bit for a negative sign? Since we don't meassure negative pressures, would a more accurate answer be 23 bits?

And also for the minimum pressure, I could happen to meassure 9.9999 Pa and would want to store this correctly, so 4 decimals. 
Since I could do the same type of calculation and end up with

2^13<9999<2^14-1

Is this already covered in the 23-24 bits I chose first?

I'm very new to this so any help or just clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are asking this question for (i.) academic interest or (ii.) are really short on storage - neither of which I am going to address - I would strongly advocate that you don't worry about the numbers of bits and instead use a standard float (4 bytes) or double (8 bytes). Databases and software packages understand floats and doubles. If you try to craft your own floating point format using the minimum number of bits then you are adding a lot of work for yourself.

A float will hold 7 significant digits, whereas a double will hold 16. If you want to get technical a float (single precision) uses 8 bits for the exponent, 1 bit for the sign and the remaining 23 bits for the significand, whilst a double (double precision) uses 11 bits for the exponent, 1 bit for the sign and 52 bits for the significand.

So I suggest you focus instead on whether a float or a double best meets your needs.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I hope it addresses what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I would have gotten to that conclusion hopefully if this indeed was an industrial question and just a matter of practicality, but the reason is academic interest. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Treating it as an academic exercise an approach is probably to identify (i.) how many digits of precision you need and (ii.) how large an exponent you need. For example if you wanted to allow 5 significant digits (so 0-99999) then you would need 17 bits (which can hold 0-131071), if your exponent you wanted from E0 to E7 then that's only 3 bits (0-7). Assuming you didn't need to hold the sign (so positive numbers only) that would give you a total of (17+3=) 20 bits. Chances are that you would want to allow for more than 5 significant digits, but hopefully that gives you a possible way forward.

Comment: So, in my case; largest number that's significant is 10000100, which is 8 significant digits. Only that part gives 24 bits. And as you said, E0-E07 is three, which would represent 10000100 as 1.00001E07 which shows that the accuracy constraint is met. This adds up to 27 bits, with only positive numbers included.

This sounds more right, since the accuracy is now accounted for and that is what I had a problem with before. I couldn't really see how that was included, but with this answer, if I got it correctly, i do.